# how to connect two QTableview Widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
import os.path
import pandas as pd

class a(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        line_edit = qtw.QLineEdit(parent)
        line_edit.setMaxLength(3)
        return line_edit
class ColorDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if option.text.strip(): # condition
            option.backgroundBrush = qtg.QColor("red")

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ##Main framwork
        self.createUI()

    def createUI(self):

        self.resize(qtc.QSize(1200, 800))
        base_widget = qtw.QWidget()
        base_widget.setLayout(qtw.QHBoxLayout())
        notebook = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        base_widget.layout().addLayout(notebook)
        self.file_list = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        notebook.setSpacing(10)
        notebook.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        base_widget.layout().addLayout(self.file_list)
        spacerItem = qtw.QSpacerItem(20, 245, qtw.QSizePolicy.Minimum, qtw.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        base_widget.layout().addItem(spacerItem)
        self.setCentralWidget(base_widget)

        # self.Detailbar = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Statusbar = qtw.QTableView()
        self.stausbar_model = qtg.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.Statusbar.setModel(self.stausbar_model)
        self.Statusbar.setFixedHeight(70)
        self.Statusbar.setEditTriggers(qtw.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        notebook.addWidget(self.Statusbar)

        # CREATE THE TABLE
        self.tableWidget = qtw.QTableView(self)  # SELECTING THE VIEW
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.model = qtg.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Category', 'Time','Comment'])   # SELECTING THE MODEL - FRAMEWORK THAT HANDLES QUERIES AND EDITS
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)  # SETTING THE MODEL
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(qtw.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.Size = QTableWidgetDisabledItem(self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, self.Size)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, self.Size)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, self.Size)
        self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)
        delegate = ColorDelegate(self.tableWidget)
        # self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, delegate)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        self.file_list.addWidget(self.tableWidget)


    def populate(self):
        # GENERATE A 4x10 GRID OF RANDOM NUMBERS.
        # VALUES WILL CONTAIN A LIST OF INT.
        # MODEL ONLY ACCEPTS STRINGS - MUST CONVERT.
        csv_fname = os.path.splitext(self.fname)[0]
        edited_csv_fname = csv_fname + ".csv"
        self.data = pd.read_csv(edited_csv_fname)
        values = []
        for i in range(len(self.data.index)):
            sub_values = []
            for j in range(len(self.data.columns)):
                value = self.data.iloc[i, j]
                sub_values.append(value)
            values.append(sub_values)

        for value in values:
            row = []
            for item in value:
                cell = qtg.QStandardItem(str(item))
                row.append(cell)
            self.model.appendRow(row)

        qd = []
        for k in range(len(self.data.index)):
            qd.append(qtg.QStandardItem(str('')))
        self.stausbar_model.appendRow(qd)

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(self.__class__, self).flags(index)
        flags |= qtc.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        flags |= qtc.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        flags |= qtc.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        flags |= qtc.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled
        flags |= qtc.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        return flags

class QTableWidgetDisabledItem(qtw.QItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        qtw.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        item = qtw.QLineEdit(parent)
        item.setReadOnly(True)
        #item.setEnabled(False)
        return item

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.blockSignals(True)
        editor.setText(index.model().data(index))
        editor.blockSignals(False)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv) #it's required to save a referance to MainWindow
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    #if it goes out of scope ,it will be destroyed
```

I have two QTableview Widgets, first QtableView widgets have 26 row and 4 column and fourth column is only editable and and , second Qtableviw widgets have 1 row and 26 column, If i chnanged in first Qtablview in 4th column the background colur would change and with respect in second Qtableview Background color would change.

In  Details first Qtableview widgets have 26 row and 4 column and 4th one is only editable and second QTableview widgets have 1 row and 26 column,if i fill any tex in cell index (10,3) in first QTableview then cell colur will changes and with respective then in cell index (0,10) in second QTableview background colur would changed.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Please find Code Mention Above

Comment: @eyllanesc For the same Question Further if I want to retrieve data from CSV file and set as first QTableview widgets then how should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to detect the change of the corresponding item of the second QTableView, get the row of that item to be able to set the background color of the corresponding item of the first QTableView.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg


class QTableWidgetDisabledItem(qtw.QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.createUI()

    def createUI(self):

        self.Statusbar = qtw.QTableView(
            editTriggers=qtw.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers
        )
        self.statusbar_model = qtg.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.Statusbar.setModel(self.statusbar_model)
        self.Statusbar.setFixedHeight(70)

        self.tableWidget = qtw.QTableView(
            selectionBehavior=qtw.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows
        )
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.model = qtg.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "Category", "Time", "Comment"])
        self.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)
        for i in range(3):
            delegate = QTableWidgetDisabledItem(self.tableWidget)
            self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(i, delegate)

        self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.on_itemChanged)

        self.resize(qtc.QSize(1200, 800))
        base_widget = qtw.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(base_widget)
        notebook = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        notebook.setSpacing(10)
        notebook.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        notebook.addWidget(self.Statusbar, alignment=qtc.Qt.AlignTop)
        lay = qtw.QHBoxLayout(base_widget)
        lay.addLayout(notebook)
        self.file_list = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.file_list.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        lay.addLayout(self.file_list)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        # emulate populate
        self.model.setRowCount(26)
        self.statusbar_model.setRowCount(1)
        self.statusbar_model.setColumnCount(self.model.rowCount())

    @qtc.pyqtSlot("QStandardItem*")
    def on_itemChanged(self, item):
        if item.column() == 3:
            it = self.statusbar_model.item(0, item.row())
            if it is None:
                it = qtg.QStandardItem()
                self.statusbar_model.setItem(0, item.row(), it)
            brush = (
                qtg.QBrush(qtg.QColor("red")) if item.text().strip() else qtg.QBrush()
            )
            it.setBackground(brush)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If i wnat import csv file and then set this csv as model in populate then how can i do??